# Problem with Index in Dask with data shifting left by q

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am trying to read CSV in Dask. it reads all columns but shift them by 1 to left. So data that is supposed to be under 1st column becomes index and 2nd becomes 1st so and so forth, last column has all NaN.

An example -

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

In Dataframe it looks like this -

```
  a,b,c
1 2,3,Nan
4 5,6,Nan
7 8,9,Nan
```

Pandas has `index_col=False` functionality which lets me avoid this scenario. Is there something in Dask that can allow me to do so.

Comment: check if the raw data has `,a,b,c` as columns and not `a,b,c`

Comment: the files are coming from a system I don't have much control over that will keep sending the files in similar fashion, so even if there is not much can be done except handling it at our end.

Comment: Pandas has an option `index_col` which dictates what to make of Index column. I am looking for a similar thing.

Comment: I dont know dask system much, but thats one thing which came to my mind when i saw the question. Lets hope someone answers you. :)

Comment: Are you running on different OS (Win and Linux?) sometime their is an issue with  [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that may be interpreted as a column

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have data different that you are showing, as it works fine:

```
In []: with open('temp.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("""a,b,c
    1,2,3
    4,5,6
    7,8,9""")

In []: dd.read_csv('temp.csv').compute()
Out[]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

This is exactly the same output as `pandas.read_csv` gives.

You can use `skiprows=` and `names=` is the header of your file is something that causes problems.

Comment: That data is for illustration of the problem. Real data is something I can't share. It is happening for all the rows so `skiprows` is not an option. It happens same with pandas too but pandas has `index_col` option which resolves the issue for me.